# Fix rails bad practice make more pretty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a CSV file from my ActiveRecord. I want to display my own custom headers for the CSV file instead the attribute name. I also want to reorder the columns and not use the column order in the database table.

I am not satisfy on how repetitive and how copy paste I did and I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on a much cleaner solution.

schema:

```
create_table "myTable", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "flight_date"
    t.text "orn"
    t.text "flight_num"
    t.datetime "created_at"
end
```

code:

```
# field names and their values
questions = {
            created_at: 'DATE SUBMITTED',   
            flight_date: 'FLIGHT DATE',
            flight_num: 'FLIGHT NUMBER',
            orn: 'ORIGIN'
}
CSV.open('/user/pepe/myfile.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
    csv << questions.values
    MyModel.all.select(questionsInbound.keys).each do |inbounds|
        attributes = inbounds.attributes //put the custom header
        transformed = {
            created_at: attributes['created_at'],   
            flight_dt: attributes['flight_dt'],
            flight_num: attributes['flight_num'],
            orn: attributes['orn']
        }
        csv << transformed.values.compact # get values and filter out nil
    end
end
```

If you have notice I am literally using the same keys for questions and transformed. How can I condense the two and make them more reusable?

Comment: There are a number of style guides you can use, [such as this one from Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby), to improve the readability of your code through formatting.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. However, I would like to perhaps create a method for some of my variables. For example, I have the same attributes in questions and in transformed. How can I make it where is more reusable.

Comment: "how repetitive and how copy paste I did" - looks fine to me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ But maybe you can save a few lines with a [`Hash#slice`](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/02/06/ruby-2-5-added-hash-slice-method.html) (ruby 2.5+, [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice))

Comment: "I am literally using the same keys for questions and transformed" - yeah, so? Why exactly do you think this is a problem?

Comment: https://github.com/mak-it/xport

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev because I have thousands of line of code. I made a small sample of my code. If I could get rid off many lines by reusing my variables it will be more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
questions = {
                created_at: 'DATE SUBMITTED',   
                flight_date: 'FLIGHT DATE',
                flight_num: 'FLIGHT NUMBER',
                orn: 'ORIGIN'
    }
    CSV.open('/user/pepe/myfile.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
        csv << questions.values
        MyModel.all.select(questionsInbound.keys).each do |inbounds|
            csv << inbounds.attributes.symbolize_keys.slice(*questions.keys).values.compact
        end
    end
```

Comment: I need to rearrange the columns and that's why I have them twice. Also, they do not equal each-other. The keys do. I have `questions` for show a different header name instead the column names. You cannot rearrange them any other way apparently than creating a new hash with the order you want. My schema shows the way they are arranged.

Comment: @myhouse so you need only to use `slice` as suggested by @sergio-tulentsev. Please check my updated answer

Comment: `slice` in not needed since you do not care about the `keys` themselves instead `values_at(*questions.keys)` would suffice also the `compact` will shift the values if one happens to be `nil` also probably not useful

Comment: I see what you're saying. That's a good point.

Comment: I have a lot of true and false and I would like to replace the true and false with yes and no. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

My approach has been to come up with a Hash of Strings and Lambdas that describes the columns:

```
columns = {
  'DATE SUBMITTED' => ->(flight) { flight.created_at },
  'FLIGHT DATE'    => ->(flight) { flight.flight_date },
  'FLIGHT NUMBER'  => ->(flight) { flight.flight_num },
  'ORN'            => ->(flight) { flight.origin }
}
```

Then loop though the Hash's `#keys` and `#values`.

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << columns.keys
  flights.each do |flight|
    csv << columns.values.map { |column| column.call(flight) }
  end
end
```

I've also seen it done with Symbols refering to method names rather than lambdas.

---

However, you've also looking to call `Model.select(column_names)` which implies that you may need to come up with more data beyond just a lambda. Like, say, a `Struct`:

```
Column = Struct.new(name: name, value: callable, sql_select: nil)

columns = [
  Column.new(name: 'DATE SUBMITTED', value: ->(flight) { flight.created_at }, sql_select: 'created_at'),
  ...
]
```

CSV generation is similar:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << columns.map(&:name)
  flights.select(columns.map(&:sql_select)).each do |flight|
    csv << columns.map { |column| column.value.call(flight) }
  end
end
```

Comment: I haven't yet tried this, but if it works I am thinking accepting your answer. So far is been the neatest answer. Thanks.